# Adding external blog to SharePoint Online Search

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, rss

We have a company intranet based on SharePoint Online.

Since the built-in blogging features of SharePoint could not meet our requirements, we have set up an external blog using WordPress.

Both the blog and our intranet require authentication against our Azure Active Directory (Office365).

Technically the blog is an Azure Web app initially loaded with WordPress with Office365 authentication protecting it. It has all been configured using the out-of-the-box features of "Create new Web app with WordPress pre-loaded" in Azure. Authentication is done via OAuth and an Azure Active Directory application handling authentication/access for the blog.

The blog works fine - we really love it. But we would really like to be able to have the contents of the new blog included in SharePoint Search on our intranet.

But none of the configurations in SharePoint Search allows us to tap into the feed of the external blog with this authentication. We are already making a couple of external blogs (some of them also WordPress) accessible to SharePoint Search - but those allow anonymous access to the blog sites themselves.

So the question is - is it possible to have the content of our external blog made accessible through SharePoint Online Search?

If it is simply not possible directly in SharePoint Online - is there a work around we can use?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to add a new content source to SharePoint Online. The workaround for including ANY content outside of SharePoint Online is Cloud Hybrid Search.

1. You stand up a SharePoint 2013 or 2016 Farm with a Cloud Search Service Application.
2. Then "on-board" the Farm to your Tenant.
3. Configure Content Sources (like your blog) or any approved content source including on-prem SharePoint Web Applications, Web Sites, Databases (or other BCS sources)
4. Crawl the content.

Following the crawl the content will be available in your SharePoint Online index and find-able in SharePoint Search Centers and Delve.